# Android Studio keeps telling me method does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 1.3.2 on a mac and I have a strange problem. Look at the following piece of code:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
...
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabbed_main_activity); <-- error here
```

Although, I can compile this and it also runs well in the simulator the IDE keeps telling me that it `cannot resolve setContentView(int)`.

It seems as if `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` does not work properly in the IDE. Do I have to trigger some option in order to solve this problem?

Comment: I just tested this in my Android Studio, and it's working fine. Maybe try Build > Clean Project or Build > Rebuild Project, or restart Android Studio / your computer altogether

Comment: Tested aswell and its working fine for me... make sure that your `tabbed_main_activity` is well made aswell

Comment: I had an issue not so long ago, where my application would run, but lthe IDE showed a lot on lint errors. I managed to solve it by synchronizing gradle after cleaning. Tools > Android > Sync project with gradle files

Comment: @TaserPain: That solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with `Eclipse`, probably your class was extending from `Fragment` and then you changed to `FragmentActivity`, just do a Clean Project and `Rebuild Project`.

Working with `Android Studio`, do `Sync project with gradle files`

[image]